# How do I remove rows from a DataTable up to a certain date?

Tags: c#, .net, select, datatable, filtering

I am having trouble filtering a DataTable, say `DtFromExcel`. The DataTable does NOT have a header row, and it starts with an actual data row, and it looks something like the following.

```
1 | 05/01/2020 Fri | ABC | XYZ | ...
2 | 05/01/2020 Fri | AAA | WKV | ...
3 | 05/02/2020 Sat | BCD | OPQ | ...
4 | 05/03/2020 Sun | CDE | RST | ...
5 | 05/03/2020 Sun | EFA | FAY | ...
6 | 05/03/2020 Sun | AXG | EAS | ...
7 | 05/04/2020 Mon | DEF | LMN | ...
8 | 05/04/2020 Mon | SXA | YTR | ...
9 | 05/05/2020 Tue | DAF | AAG | ...
```

The second column contains a certain date with some extra string (day of the week), and these rows are ordered by this date column. There can be multiple rows with the same date.

Now, I want to delete rows where the date column contains a certain date AND any rows prior to that. For example, if the certain date is `05/04/2020`, then I need to delete all rows up to the 8th row, so that the remaining DataTable would have to look like

```
9 | 05/05/2020 Tue | DAF | AAG | ...
```

My problem is, first I don't know how to filter the DataTable without the column name. I thought about assigning a header row without overwriting the first actual data row, but it seems like this is a lot of work, only to filter. Second, I am not sure how to use these conditions ((a)the second column contains a certain date, `AND` (b)any row with the dates prior to that certain date).

```
private void DeleteRows(DateTime certainDate){
    DataRow[] targetRowsToDelete = dtFromExcel.Select(/* Not sure what to put in here */);
    foreach (DataRow row in targetRowsToDelete)
    {
        if (Convert.ToDateTime(row[1].ToString().Split(c" ")[0]) <= certainDate)
        DtFromExcel.Rows.Remove(row);
    }
}
```

I did not want to loop through the whole DataTable because this process occurs often in my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [empty constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.-ctor#System_Data_DataColumn__ctor) to create a `DataColumn` with no name, the documentation states...

> When created, a `DataColumn` object has no default `ColumnName` or `Caption`. When you add it to a `DataColumnCollection`, a default name (`"Column1"`, `"Column2"`, and so on) will be generated if a name has not been assigned to the `ColumnName`.

...so creating and loading a `DataTable` like this...

```cs
const string Input = @"1 | 05/01/2020 Fri | ABC | XYZ | ...
2 | 05/01/2020 Fri | AAA | WKV | ...
3 | 05/02/2020 Sat | BCD | OPQ | ...
4 | 05/03/2020 Sun | CDE | RST | ...
5 | 05/03/2020 Sun | EFA | FAY | ...
6 | 05/03/2020 Sun | AXG | EAS | ...
7 | 05/04/2020 Mon | DEF | LMN | ...
8 | 05/04/2020 Mon | SXA | YTR | ...
9 | 05/05/2020 Tue | DAF | AAG | ...";
DtFromExcel = new DataTable();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
    Console.WriteLine($"Column {i} has ColumnName \"{column.ColumnName}\"");

    DtFromExcel.Columns.Add(column);
    Console.WriteLine($"Column {i} has ColumnName \"{column.ColumnName}\"");
}

foreach (string line in Input.Split("\r\n"))
{
    string[] fields = line.Split(" | ");

    DtFromExcel.Rows.Add(fields);
}
```

...produces this output...

```
Column 0 has ColumnName ""
Column 0 has ColumnName "Column1"
Column 1 has ColumnName ""
Column 1 has ColumnName "Column2"
Column 2 has ColumnName ""
Column 2 has ColumnName "Column3"
Column 3 has ColumnName ""
Column 3 has ColumnName "Column4"
Column 4 has ColumnName ""
Column 4 has ColumnName "Column5"
```

...so you could always use those default names.  Further, just because your input data doesn't specify column/field names doesn't mean you can't do so after it's been loaded into the `DataTable`...

```cs
DtFromExcel.Columns[1].ColumnName = "MyDateColumn";
```

Either way, you'll have a known name by which you can refer to that column.

As to your comment about not wanting to "loop through the whole `DataTable`", it's not clear if you mean because of the additional code or perhaps performance implications, but to the latter point even if you don't explicitly loop through and test every `DataRow`, `Select()` **will**.  On that note, since you say the rows are ordered by date, you can exploit that [using LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable) to stop scanning rows as soon as a date outside the search range is found...

```cs
private static DateTime GetRowDate(DataRow row) => DateTime.ParseExact(
    (string) row["MyDateColumn"], "MM/dd/yyyy ddd", null
);

private void DeleteRows(DateTime maxDate)
{
    DataRow[] rowsToRemove = DtFromExcel.AsEnumerable()
        .TakeWhile(row => GetRowDate(row) <= maxDate)
        .ToArray();// Required to prevent "Collection was modified" exception in foreach below

    foreach (DataRow row in rowsToRemove)
        DtFromExcel.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

If your rows aren't guaranteed to be sorted by date, then you can substitute [`Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) for [`TakeWhile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile) and it will work just the same.

As for your original request to use [`DateTable.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select), I'm not sure if that's even feasible here since your dates appear to be stored as `string`, not `DateTime`, in your `DataColumn`.  I see that the [expression syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression) supports a `CONVERT()` [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression#functions) that can convert between `String` and `DateTime`, but I can't imagine that would be any more performant or readable than LINQ so I wouldn't pursue that unless you absolutely have to.